VSCode extension webviews mixed tree views
I'm trying to build VSCode extension where i want to have a button on top of tree view views. I created a webview for it, but when webview is listed with tree views it displays as tree view and also has expand icon in the top left corner. How can i implement this feature, having a fixed container with button on top of tree views.
package.json example
 "contributes": {
    "viewsContainers": {
      "activitybar": [
        {
          "id": "demoExtension",
          "title": "Demo",
          "icon": "$(heart)"
        }
      ]
    },
    "views": {
      "demoExtension": [
        {
          "type": "webview",
          "id": "Click Me",
          "name": ""
        },
        {
          "type": "tree",
          "id": "item-1",
          "name": "Item 1"
        },
        {
          "type": "tree",
          "id": "item-2",
          "name": "Item 2"
        }
      ]
    },
   }

